# calling func. change the input

Tags: python

I need to write a program that receives list of numbers and show the cumulative sum, only with recursion!

for example:

input:

```
1,2,3
```

output:

```
1,3,6
```

my problem is that I have some tests to run on the function and I have to get true for all of them, but I get false b/c my func change the input.
someone have an idea how to fix it? (and I cant change the tests of course..)

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
        ''' Input: numbers - a list of numbers,
                Output: a list of cumulative sums of the numbers'''
        if len(numbers) == 0 : return numbers
        if len(numbers) == 1 : return numbers
        numbers[1] = numbers[0] + numbers[1]
        return [numbers[0]] + rec_cumsum(numbers[1:])

### Testing code

def test_rec_cumsum(numbers):
        return rec_cumsum(numbers) == [sum(numbers[:i]) for i in range(1,len(numbers)+1)]

import random
print test_rec_cumsum([1,2,3])
print test_rec_cumsum(random.sample(range(100),30))
print test_rec_cumsum([])
```

Comment: You can create a copy of the input list in your function and change it in any way you like. But since the function is recursive, you can end up using much more memory than actually needed.

Comment: yes it has to be with recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basicly the same, but it does not change the value of numbers.

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 0 : return numbers
    if len(numbers) == 1 : return numbers
    return [numbers[0]] + rec_cumsum([numbers[0]+numbers[1]] + numbers[2:])
```

Comment: it works! thanks!
can you just explain what the different between the codes?

Comment: I can. Though I think you should play around with lists in an interactive shell a little. However, when [numbers[0]+numbers[1]] is parsed as [1+2] and will therefor result in [3]. When you add two lists in python, the latter list will be appended to the first.

Comment: The default call stack limit is 1000. From frame 0 that lets `rec_cumsum` handle a list of up to 999 numbers, but the deeper the calling frame, the smaller the upper limit before the interpreter raises a `RuntimeError`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second list:

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 0: return []
    sums = [ numbers[0] ]
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        sums.append(sums[i-1] + numbers[i])
    return sums
```

Comment: `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`

Comment: sorry  I forgot to mention that it has to be with recursion!

Comment: @LevLevitsky oops, fixed that.