# Recursion code in python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm new to python and trying to solve my homework... I'm trying to create a recursion function that takes a list of numbers [a, b, c....] and turns it to this list: [a, a+b, a+b+c, ....].

This is my code:

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    ''' Input: numbers - a list of numbers,
            Output: a list of cumulative sums of the numbers'''
    new_list=numbers
    last=new_list[-1]
    if numbers==[]:
         return numbers
    if len(numbers) == 1:
         return numbers[0]
    new_list.remove(last)
    rec= rec_cumsum(new_list)
    new_list.append(rec+last)
    return last+rec
```

this works but because I used return for last+rec, I can't use return to get the list back (new_list). Please explain to me what did I do wrong... thanks!

Comment: You'll have to fix your indentation first, this is not valid Python code as it stands.

Comment: I don't know why it copied my code like that but the indentation is correct in the code itself.

Comment: Then you are mixing tabs and spaces. *Don't do that*. Stick to spaces instead, configure your editor to convert tabs to spaces.

Comment: It was a weird tab thing. I fix it.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto: way ahead of you. Not weird, SO uses 4 spaces for tabs when displaying, 8 when editing..

Comment: Thank you Martin, I will....

Comment: @user1797938 Is a recursion based solution a compulsion here?

Comment: `new_list.remove(last)` will lead to an error if `last` occurs more than once in `numbers`. (`remove` will remove the first occurrence of `last`, while you want to remove the last occurrence.)

Comment: Also why not try for another argument in the function that holds in the updated list, so you will return the sum , updated_list ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13397445/989121

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's write some test cases and practice some test-driven development:

```
tests = [[],         # Desired answer: []
         [1],        # [1]
         [1,2],      # [1, 3] 
         [1,2,3],    # [1, 3, 6]
         [1,2,1,3]]  # [1, 3, 4, 7]
for t in tests:
    print(rec_cumsum(t))
```

If we add this to your code and [run it, we get](http://ideone.com/0poZkF):

```
    last=new_list[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why is this? Apparently -1 is an out-of-range index. Why wouldn't `new_list` have a -1 index?

Aha. That happens if `new_list` is empty. So we need to address the base case first. While we're at it, let's also use @MartijnPieters' suggestion:

```
if len(numbers) <= 1:
     return numbers
```

to obtain

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    ''' Input: numbers - a list of numbers,
            Output: a list of cumulative sums of the numbers'''
    if len(numbers) <= 1:
         return numbers
    new_list=numbers
    last=new_list[-1]
    new_list.remove(last)
    rec = rec_cumsum(new_list)
    new_list.append(rec[-1]+last)
    return last+rec
```

Now run the test again. [This time we get](http://ideone.com/r53hcb)

```
    return last+rec
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

So now Python is saying `last` is an `int` and `rec` is a `list`, and we can not add the two together.

Okay, `rec` should be a list since it is the return value of `rec_cumsum(new_list)`. What should replace `last+rec`?

Let's think in terms of a concrete example. If `rec` is `[a, a+b]` then we want to return `[a, a+b, a+b+c]`. How do we form `a+b+c`?

How about adding the last element in `rec` with the last element of `numbers`:

```
rec[-1]+last
```

We want to append this to the end of `rec`:

```
rec.append(rec[-1]+last)
```

Let's make that change and see what happens. But while we're editing, let's also clean up some code we never use. We can delete `new_list.append(rec[-1]+last)`:

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    ''' Input: numbers - a list of numbers,
            Output: a list of cumulative sums of the numbers'''
    if len(numbers) <= 1:
         return numbers
    new_list=numbers
    last=new_list[-1]
    new_list.remove(last)
    rec = rec_cumsum(new_list)
    rec.append(rec[-1]+last)
    return rec
```

[Now our program returns](http://ideone.com/OGC5sS)

```
[]
[1]
[1, 3]
[1, 3, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 7]
```

Hurray, our program runs without errors. But wait... it returns the wrong results. Look at the last line.

`rec_cumsum([1,2,1,3])` is returning `[2,3,4,7]` whereas the correct answer is `[1,3,4,7]`. Why is the first number wrong?

It has to do with `new_list.remove(last)`. This command removes the *first* occurrence of `last` from `new_list`. We want to remove the *last* occurrence.

So instead, let's use

```
new_list = numbers[:-1]
```

So the program becomes:

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    ''' Input: numbers - a list of numbers,
            Output: a list of cumulative sums of the numbers'''
    if len(numbers) <= 1:
         return numbers
    new_list=numbers[:-1]
    last=numbers[-1]
    rec = rec_cumsum(new_list)
    rec.append(rec[-1]+last)
    return rec
```

[Run the tests](http://ideone.com/Coi3Cm). It works! Now it is a good practice to look back at our solution and see how it can be tightened up and made more elegant.
I see we used `new_list` and `last` as temporary variables. Do we really need them?

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers):
    if len(numbers)<=1:
        return numbers
    result = rec_cumsum(numbers[:-1])
    result.append(result[-1]+numbers[-1])
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

Your function should always return a list; for the empty list case, an empty list, and for the case where there is only one element, a *list with only one element*.

But your code returns the one element, not a list with one element:

```
if len(numbers) == 1:
     return numbers[0]
```

Change that to returning just `numbers`:

```
if len(numbers) == 1:
     return numbers
```

You can combine this with the other end-state test:

```
if len(numbers) < 2:
     return numbers
```

Next problem is that you are not creating a copy of a list when you create the variable `new_list`; you create a reference to *the same list*, you'd have to use a slice or create an explicit new list:

```
new_list = numbers[:]
```

If you are going to remove a value from that list anyway, you may as well adjust the slice a little, and put this *after* testing `numbers` (why do the work otherwise):

```
if len(numbers) < 2:
     return numbers
new_list = numbers[:-1]
last = numbers[-1]
```

Nowhere in your code do you actually compute a sum; nothing is added to your numbers. You never add `a` to `b`, `c`, etc. Moreover, you seem to be focusing on the *last* number, while your assignment states you needed to sum the *first* value to the rest of the list.

And there is a pattern there. Not only do you add `a` to `b`, but the sum of `a` + `b` is added to `c`, and that sum is then added to `d`, etc. Let's make use of that:

```
def rec_cumsum(numbers, culmulated_sum=0):
    if len(numbers) < 1:
        return numbers
    sum = numbers[0] + culmulated_sum
    return [sum] + rec_cumsum(numbers[1:], sum)
```

Note that I don't even *bother* storing a copy of numbers now; may as well just pass it to the next recursion as a slice of everything but the first element. We also use the *first* element from `numbers` to create our sum (`numbers[0]`).

Also, we now pass along the culmulative sum so far, starting at 0; and that means we need to change the end condition of the recursive function; we are essentially adding `[0]` to the start of the list, and we want to make sure we sum that with the next element always.

This now does what you need:

```
>>> rec_cumsum([5, 1, 10, 2, 3])
[5, 6, 16, 18, 21]
```